# How to concatenate group members into a resulting column of an SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 related tables as given below where I need to concatenate the names of group members into a query result as given below:

[image]

I am not sure whether this is possible with SQL. I tried to use `group by`, but I do not know a useful expression to search for `concatenation` in the context of `group by`. Any hints where and with what key words to search for will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're really asking how to do something similar to MySQL's `group_concat`. Have you tried searching for that?

Comment: No, I did not know that there is a feature such as group_concat. I will look into it

Comment: Be aware that `group_concat` is a MySQL feature, so you would have to look for the equivalent in Microsoft SQL Server's syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `String_agg` as follows

```
SELECT groupid,
       groupname,
       String_agg(groupmembername, ',') AS GroupMemberName
FROM   lefttable1 t1
       JOIN righttable2 t2
         ON t1.groupid = t2.groupid
GROUP  BY groupid,
          groupname
```

or as follows

```
SELECT groupid,
       groupname,
       String_agg(groupmembername, ',') AS GroupMemberName
FROM   (SELECT groupid,
               groupname,
               groupmembername
        FROM   lefttable1 t1
               JOIN righttable2 t2
                 ON t1.groupid = t2.groupid) T3
```